# How to indent group of lines multiple times

Tags: vim

In Vim <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>></kbd> will shift the five lines below and including the one the cursor is one tab or `shiftwidth` spaces right. <kbd>5</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd><</kbd> does the same to the left.

What do I do if I want to shift some number of lines twice or three times left or right? I'm looking for somehow specifying the number of shiftwidth's to shift instead of <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>></kbd>

Comment: i usually just do `5>>` followed by `.` as many times as i need.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9795/2920

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use visual selection to select the lines:

e.g. to indent the current line and the next 4 lines, select with <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>

and then use a number followed by `>` to indent that many times e.g. <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

Answer (score 2):

From `vim` official manual: `:help >`

> To move a line several 'shiftwidth's, use Visual mode or the : commands.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>     Vjj4>           move three lines 4 indents to the right
>     :<<<            move current line 3 indents to the left
>     :>> 5           move 5 lines 2 indents to the right
>     :5>>            move line 5 2 indents to the right
> ```

Or simply, `5>>` and repeat the command with `.` in normal mode as @acushner pointed out

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
nnoremap > :<C-u>exec 'set shiftwidth='.v:count1<cr>>
nnoremap < :<C-u>exec 'set shiftwidth='.v:count1<cr><
xnoremap > :<C-u>exec 'set shiftwidth='.v:count1<cr>gv>
xnoremap < :<C-u>exec 'set shiftwidth='.v:count1<cr>gv<
```

This way, something like `5>>` will indent the current line with 5 spaces. This isn't the perfect solution because there are many different ways you might want to do this. For example, what if you want this to be 5 tabs instead? Or 5 times the current setting of `sw`? But that comes down to personal preference and you didn't really specify this in your question, so if you do want to do something like that, I'll let you figure it out.

But for example, if you know you want 4 spaces, you could do:

```
nnoremap > :<C-u>exec 'set shiftwidth=4*'.v:count1<cr>>
nnoremap < :<C-u>exec 'set shiftwidth=4*'.v:count1<cr><
xnoremap > :<C-u>exec 'set shiftwidth=4*'.v:count1<cr>gv>
xnoremap < :<C-u>exec 'set shiftwidth=4*'.v:count1<cr>gv<
```

But this doesn't take into account if you're using a smaller shiftwidth.

Comment: that doesn't really solve my problem, it just changes it from "how do I get the Y times part which is currently stuck at 1 with `5>>`" to "how do I get the X times part which would be stuck at 1 with `5>>`"

Comment: @Austin_Anderson You have to essentially separate the count and the motion. The count is everything before the first `>` and the count is everything after the first `>`. So you could do either `5>5>` or `5>4j`

Answer (score 0):

Anoter option using command

```
4:>>>
```

When you press `<Enter>` you will see:

```
:.,.+3>>>
```

Then press `<Enter>`